# Verilog: ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 117: Syntax error near "else"

Tags: verilog

I'm tring to use fpga board to display graphical objects on screen via vga. In the code below, "flag" is only 1 bit. What I want to achieve is that when "flag" is 1, I make certain region one color; when "flag" is 0, it display another color. Verilog ISE keeps telling me that I have an error near the "else" statement in the code below(the "else" in the middle). Can anyone please tell me why?

```
        if (vc >= (groundTop) && vc < (groundBottom))
            begin
                red = 3'b111;
                green = 3'b111;
                blue = 2'b11;
            end
        // player level
        else if (vc >= (groundTop-playerSize) && vc < groundTop)
            begin

                if (flag==1)
                    begin
                        if (hc >= (hbp+p1nbr*playerMove-playerMove*p1nbl) && hc < (hbp+playerSize+p1nbr*playerMove-playerMove*p1nbl))
                            begin
                                red = 0;
                                green = 0;
                                blue = 0;
                            end
                        else
                            begin
                                red = 3'b000;
                                green = 3'b111;
                                blue = 2'b11;
                            end
                    end

                else
                    begin
                        else if (hc >= (hbp+p1nbr*playerMove-playerMove*p1nbl) && hc < (hbp+playerSize+p1nbr*playerMove-playerMove*p1nbl))
                            begin
                                red = 3'b111;
                                green = 3'b111;
                                blue = 2'b00;
                            end
                        else
                            begin
                                red = 3'b000;
                                green = 3'b111;
                                blue = 2'b11;
                            end
                    end
            end
        //sky
        else 
            begin
                red = 3'b000;
                green = 3'b111;
                blue = 2'b11;
            end
```

and here's how the error looks like.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "U:/public/work/ECEG_240/NERP_demo/vga640x480.v" Line 117: Syntax error near "else".
ERROR:ProjectMgmt - 1 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which `else` is causing the error? There are many (even "in the middle"). Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the

`else if (hc >= (hbp+p1nbr*playerMove-playerMove*p1nbl) && hc < (hbp+playerSize+p1nbr*playerMove-playerMove*p1nbl))`

There is no reason for that to be an `else if`. Instead it should be a simple `if` since there isn't another if to match the else to.